# Recalculate/Reinitialise directive - after async data fetch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive kind of like this:

```
function timeDisplay() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.tooltip = scope.minutes > 60 ? (scope.minutes / 60) + " hrs" : scope.minutes + " mins";
        },
        replace: true,
        template: "<abbr uib-tooltip='{{ tooltip }}'>{{ minutes }}</abbr>", 
        scope: {
            minutes: "="
        }
    };
    return directive;
}
```

In some places, like on an `ng-repeat`, this works fine. But in other places, where my page controller is fetching data from the server, it's not.

The issue seems to be that the link function is firing when the page is being parsed, so when the data comes back from the server, the link function is not 're-run', so the tooltip is never set because the first time it ran the `minutes` was empty.

When it's in an `ng-repeat`, then the link function is only called when the data is already there, so it's fine.

How do I re-run the link function, or what is a better pattern for this directive to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have `<custom obj="object"></custom>`. Link function wont be called again if you modify object. What you can do:

1. Best - rewrite directive, so it watches object (`$scope.$watch('obj')` in directive)and if it changes directive updates itself. (This is how ng-bind, ng-repeat, ... works) Or you can use events.
2. If you receive object only once - just use ng-if, i.e. if object is promise:

> ```
> <custom obj="object" ng-if="object.$resolved"></custom>
> ```

3. Pathetic fake ng-repeat:

> ```
> <div ng-repeat="a in fakeArray">
>     <custom obj="object"></custom>
> </div>
> ```

Here assigning fakeArray to ['anything'] will remove old element and add new.